# Assigning closure with closure parameter

Tags: swift, closures

Suppose I have this class

```
class ClosureTest{
    var nestedClosure: (((String) -> Void) -> Void)?
}
```

How do I assign a value to `nestedClosure`?

I tried the code below but I'm getting an error. Can someone help explain please?

```
let cTest = ClosureTest()
cTest.nestedClosure = {{ myStr -> Void in } -> Void }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, typealiases will help to reduce all the paranthesis in your code:

```
typealias InnerClosure = ((String) -> Void)

class ClosureTest{
    var nestedClosure: ((InnerClosure) -> Void)?
}
```

When you want to assing a value to `nestedClosure`, you need to provide a closure that takes an `InnerClosure` as single argument and returns nothing, hence:

```
let cTest = ClosureTest()
cTest.nestedClosure = { (arg:InnerClosure) in
    print ("calling arg from nestedClosure:")
    arg("called from outer space") // call the inner closure
}
```

To use the `nestedClosure`, you need to provide a concrete *value* of type `InnerClosure`:

```
let innerClosureValue:InnerClosure = { txt in
    print ("the inner closure; txt: \(txt)")
}

cTest.nestedClosure?(innerClosureValue)
```

The output then is:

> calling arg from nestedClosure:
> the inner closure; txt: called from outer space

Alternatively, without the `innerClosureValue` variable:

```
cTest.nestedClosure?({ txt in
    print ("Or this: \(txt)")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the Optional bit for a second, `(((String) -> Void) -> Void)` is:

- A function...

  - That takes a function...

    - That takes a string
    - And returns Void
  - And returns Void

So a useful version of this would be:

```
{ f in f("x") }
```

In this, `f` is a `(String) -> Void`. It will be passed to the closure, and then the closure passed `"x"` to it.

For the trivial version that does nothing (like in your example), the code would be:

```
{ _ in }
```

That says "this closure takes one parameter and doesn't do anything with it."

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
var nestedClosure:((String) -> Void)?
```

With

```
cTest.nestedClosure = { myStr in

}
```

Comment: Well, this does not meet the _suppose I have this class..._ requirement, since it changes the whole problem